How to handle click event in Swiperjs
I am using swiper.js and my code:


$(function () {

var elements = new Swiper(".elements", {
    effect: "fade",
    spaceBetween: 10,
    mousewheel: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    fadeEffect: {
      crossFade: true,
    }
});

$(".element li").on("click", function () {
  var element = $(this).attr('aria-label');
  
  $(".element li").removeClass("actived");
  $(this).addClass("actived");
});

$('.elements .swiper-slide[aria-label="' + element + '"').addClass("swiper-slide-active swiper-slide-visible");

});
.element li {color:blue;}
.element li.actived {color:red;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<div>
  <div class="swiper elements">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://clubhouse.swingu.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/philcareer.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://clubhouse.swingu.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/2025schedule.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://clubhouse.swingu.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/scottiefedex.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="element">
    <ul>
      <li aria-label="1 / 3">One</li>
      <li aria-label="2 / 3">Two</li>
      <li aria-label="3 / 3">Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

</html>



I can't add class swiper-slide-active swiper-slide-visible when I use:
$('.elements .swiper-slide[aria-label="' + element + '"').addClass("swiper-slide-active swiper-slide-visible");
Can you help me? Thank you!

Try use slideTo() method, instead adding classes manually by aria-label.


$(function () {
      var elements = new Swiper(".elements", {
        effect: "fade",
        spaceBetween: 10,
        mousewheel: true,
        grabCursor: true,
        fadeEffect: {
          crossFade: true,
        },
      });

      $(".element li").on("click", function () {
        var elementIndex = $(this).index();
        
        $(".element li").removeClass("actived");
        $(this).addClass("actived");

        elements.slideTo(elementIndex);
      });
    });
.element li {
      color: blue;
      cursor: pointer;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
.element li.actived {
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<div>
    <div class="swiper elements">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" aria-label="1 / 3">
          <img src="https://clubhouse.swingu.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/philcareer.jpg" alt="One" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" aria-label="2 / 3">
          <img src="https://clubhouse.swingu.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/2025schedule.jpg" alt="Two" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" aria-label="3 / 3">
          <img src="https://clubhouse.swingu.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/scottiefedex.jpg" alt="Three" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="element">
      <ul>
        <li aria-label="1 / 3">One</li>
        <li aria-label="2 / 3">Two</li>
        <li aria-label="3 / 3">Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>



